# Binding static class property failing in <SwitchCell>

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this C# code

```
public static class AS
{
    public static bool ss;  // Show Subcategory
}

public SettingsPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

}

void SsSwitch(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
   App.DB.UpdateBoolSetting(Settings.Ss, e.Value);
   //
   // code here will update the value of AS.ss
   // after the database has been updated
   //
}
```

this XAML

```
<SwitchCell x:Name="SWCData" Text="Select Your Network" 
     On="{Binding AS.ss}" OnChanged="SsSwitch" />
```

I am getting a message saying that no property or bindable property for the view.

Can anyone give me help on this?

Comment: You have set BindingContext as CommandViewModel and there is no property called abc in CommandViewModel class. Try to set BindingContext = this or add abc property in CommandViewModel class. Also abc property should be bool abc {get;set;}

Comment: Hi, actually the binding would need to be to the static class value AS.ss.  Sorry I just put abc in there but changed it soon after.  How could I add the value AS.ss to the CommandViewModel or how could I change the binding to point to AS.ss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding static class then refer the below code to bind

```
<SwitchCell  Text="Select Your Network" 
                           On="{Binding Source={x:Static local:AS.ss}}" OnChanged="SsSwitch" />
```